# Things to be consider while updating jquery version from v2.1.3 to v3.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

> I need to update the jquery version from 2.1.3 to 3.5.1
> But I'm not sure about the breaking functionality.
> What should I have to do.
> If we are working in a big project where we are not aware of most of the functionality related to jquery and later we need to update its version as I mentioned then what should I consider the things while updating.
> I need to update three files (jquery, jquery.min.js and jquery.min.map )

Comment: Back up the software and begin testing new version.  Look for error messages and search them on stack. Describe issues with code words here in your question. The answers will trickle in.  You might find HTML and CSS work arounds. It might be a time to consider abandoning jQuery. Or, you might have issues that don't require another framework.  The more details you provide, the more information you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to migrate Jquery to 3.x version, [Jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#README) plugin is used. In order to use this plugin you need version atleast 1.12.x or 2.2.x version. Since you have 2.1.3 version, you need to convert it to latest 2.x version. For this [Jquery-migrate-1.x](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable#readme) is used.

Steps to migrate

1. Upgrade the version of jQuery on the page to the latest 1.x or 2.x
   version.
2. Add the uncompressed jQuery Migrate 1.x Plugin to the page.
3. Test the page and resolve any warnings that appear on the
   console, using the [JQMIGRATE 1.x](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/warnings.md) warning documentation as a guide.
4. After resolving all the warnings on the console Remove the jQuery Migrate 1.x
   plugin and ensure that the updated jQuery code on the page continues to work
   properly with only the latest jQuery 1.x/2.x in use.
5. Upgrade the version of jQuery on thepage to the latest 3.x version and add the
   uncompressed jQuery Migrate 3.x plugin to the page.
6. Test the page and resolve any warnings that appear on the console, using the
   [JQMIGRATE 3.x warning](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md) documentation as a guide.
7. After resolving all the warnings, Remove the jQuery Migrate 3.x plugin and
   ensure that the page continues to work properly with only the latest jQuery
   3.x in use.

Read this [doc](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin) for more information